# How to construct a subring of a polynomial ring in Magma

Tags: symbolic-computation, computer-algebra-systems

This question is about the [computer algebra system Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) (*not* the [linear algebra library](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/)), and is [crossposted from scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/how-to-construct-a-subring-of-a-polynomial-ring-in-magma).

Please forgive if this is off-topic; I am a regular user of the StackExchange network but this is my first post on StackOverflow. [I am looking](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/is-either-math-se-or-stackoverflow-an-appropriate-forum-for-questions-about-magm) for the right home for this kind of question. (In principle it seems to me to be [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions) but it hasn't gotten an answer in 4 days so I wanted to know if StackOverflow yielded a different result.)

> Suppose one has constructed a polynomial algebra A over a ring R in Magma. How does one construct the sub-R-algebra of A generated by a given list of elements of A?

This seems to me to be a very basic operation so I can't believe there isn't a way to do it, but I haven't so far found it in [the handbook](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/). (I see functionality to construct subalgebras of matrix algebras and of endomorphism rings of abelian varieties, but not polynomial rings.)

Comment: Crossposted to [SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/how-to-construct-a-subring-of-a-polynomial-ring-in-magma).